# Finding the conditional probability of indicator function

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation

Given the following joint pdf: $$f(x,y)=2x^{y-1}y^2e^{-y^2}, 0<x \leq 1, y \geq 0$$

We want to estimate $\theta=P\{X >\frac{Y}{Y+1}\}$. Consider $Z = I(X > \frac{Y}{Y+1})$. Generate a value of $g(Y) = E(Z|Y)$.

One approach seems to derive the marginal pdf $f(x)$ and then finding $\int_{\frac{y}{y+1}}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ since $E(Z|Y)=P(X > \frac{Y}{Y+1}|Y)$. Would this be correct? However, finding $f(x)$ seems tedious. I'm thinking using an importance sampling estimator may be a good approach. What do you think?

Comment: @herbsteinberg It is correct as written.  Over the interval $x \in (0,1]$, the marginal density of $Y$ becomes $$f_Y(y) = \int_{x=0}^1 2x^{y-1} y^2 e^{-y^2} \, dx = 2y e^{-y^2},$$ which in turn integrates to $1$ over $y > 0$.

Comment: I cancelled my first comment.  I realized my (dumb) error.  In any case would changing the question to the equivalent $P(\frac{X}{1-X}\gt Y)$ make it easier?

Comment: @herbsteinberg Interesting... haven't thought of that. It seems like I would still need to use $f_{X}(x)$ to compute that probability. One approach I'm considering is computing $f(x|y) = yx^{y-1}$, then I can compute the cdf $F(x|y) = x^y$ and then $P(X > \frac{Y}{Y+1}|Y) = 1 - F(\frac{Y}{Y+1}|Y) = 1 - (\frac{Y}{Y+1})^Y$. However, I feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

The desired probability can be computed by integrating the joint density over the region of interest:
$$\begin{align*}
\Pr[X > Y/(1+Y)] &= \int_{y=0}^\infty \int_{x=y/(1+y)}^1 2x^{y-1} y^2 e^{-y^2} \, dx \, dy \\
&= \int_{y=0}^\infty 2y^2 e^{-y^2} \left[\frac{x^y}{y}\right]_{x=y/(1+y)}^1 \, dy \\
&= \int_{y=0}^\infty 2y e^{-y^2} \left(1 - \frac{y^y}{(1+y)^y}\right) \, dy \\
\end{align*}$$
and at this point, it should be obvious that there is no closed form solution; however, numeric calculation is possible, giving
$$0.46356908561532520568025428073320140197640792196629\ldots.$$
The integrand rapidly converges to $0$ as $y \to \infty$, so numeric evaluation proceeds easily.